# Шифр Виженера. Шифровка/расшифровка

Tags: python, шифрование

Задача:
Зашифровать текст шифром Виженера, потом надо будет еще и расшифровать, но это уже другая история. Текст состоит из маленьких английских букв и пробелов. Обработки пробелов пока нет. Так как застрял на первом тесте. В комментариях указан зашифрованный текст, т.е ответ.

В чем может быть проблема?

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def encrypt(key, plaintext):
    key *= len(plaintext) // len(key) + 1
    ciphered = ''.join([chr((ord(chplain) + ord(key[indx])) % 26 + ord('a')) for indx, chplain in enumerate(plaintext)])
    return ciphered

print(encrypt('klic', 'tajnytext'))                    # dlrpiemzd
print(encrypt('klic', 'tajny text s mezerama'))        # dlrpi emzd d ugjpzcwl
print(encrypt('dlouhyklic', 'mega zasifrovany text'))  # ppuu gyctntrgohf roib
```

UPD: Всем спасибо

Теперь следующий пункт обработчик пробелов.
Я сделал так:

```
def encrypt(key, plaintext):
ord_a = ord('a')
key *= len(plaintext) // len(key) + 1
ciphered = ''
for indx, chplain in enumerate(plaintext):
    if chplain == ' ':
        ciphered += ' '
    else:
        ciphered += chr(((ord(chplain)-ord_a) + (ord(key[indx])-ord_a))%26 + ord_a)

return ciphered
```

После пробела шифр сбивается. У меня есть идея, что это связано с indx, но как это проверить или поправить идей нет. Жду комментариев

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка из-за того, что для деления по модулю 26 вы берете порядковый номер букв в ASCII, а нужно брать номер буквы в алфавите. Отсюда получается разница в 12 (два раза по 6 - разница между 97%26 и номером буквы "а" в алфавите).

Поправленный код:

```
ciphered = ''.join([chr(((ord(chplain)-ord('a')) + (ord(key[indx])-ord('a')))%26 + ord('a')) for indx, chplain in enumerate(plaintext)])
```

Чтобы не высчитывать по нескольку раз `ord('a')` для каждой буквы, можно сразу положить значение в переменную:

```
def encrypt(key, plaintext):
    ord_a = ord('a')
    key *= len(plaintext) // len(key) + 1
    ciphered = ''.join([chr(((ord(chplain)-ord_a) + (ord(key[indx])-ord_a))%26 + ord_a) for indx, chplain in enumerate(plaintext)])
    return ciphered
```

Пробелы, как и в вашем коде, не обрабатываются, поэтому после первого же пробела шифрованный текст не совпадает с ответом.

Comment: можно слегка упростить используя itertools.cycle и zip: `encrypt = lambda key, plaintext: ''.join([chr(a + ((c-a) + (k-a)) % 26) for c, k in zip(map(ord, plaintext), cycle(map(ord, key)))])`

Answer (score -1):

[**Шифр Виженера**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)

```
tabula_recta = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def encrypt(key, text):
    result = []
    space = 0
    for index, ch in enumerate(text):
        if ch != ' ':
            mj = tabula_recta.index(ch)
            kj = tabula_recta.index(key[(index - space) % len(key)])
            cj = (mj + kj) % len(tabula_recta)
            result.append(tabula_recta[cj])
        else:
            space += 1
            result.append(' ')
    return ''.join(result)

def decrypt(key, text):
    result = []
    space = 0
    for index, ch in enumerate(text):
        if ch != ' ':
            cj = tabula_recta.index(ch)
            kj = tabula_recta.index(key[(index - space) % len(key)])
            mj = (cj - kj) % len(tabula_recta)
            result.append(tabula_recta[mj])
        else:
            space += 1
            result.append(' ')
    return ''.join(result)

print(encrypt('klic', 'tajnytext'))                    # dlrpiemzd
print(encrypt('klic', 'tajny text s mezerama'))        # dlrpi emzd d ugjpzcwl
print(encrypt('dlouhyklic', 'mega zasifrovany text'))  # ppuu gyctntrgohf roib

print(decrypt('klic', 'dlrpiemzd'))                    # tajnytext
print(decrypt('klic', 'dlrpi emzd d ugjpzcwl'))        # tajny text s mezerama
print(decrypt('dlouhyklic', 'ppuu gyctntrgohf roib'))  # mega zasifrovany text
```